# Is there a convention for throwing many similar error messages when unit tests fail?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests, and am raising many similar error messsages to the point where the code looks very messy.

Something like this:

```py
# Test that compare_pass1 is downstream to secondary_pass1
self.assertTrue(
    all(
        task in all_downstream_task_for_secondary_pass1_task
        for task in {compare_pass1}
    ),
    f'One of {compare_pass1} not found in downstream to {secondary_pass1_task task}',
)

# Check that primary_pass1 is upstream to secondary_pass1
self.assertTrue(
    all(
        task in all_upstream_task_for_secondary_pass1_task
        for task in {primary_pass1_task}
    ),
    f'One of {primary_pass1_task} not found in upstream to {secondary_pass1_task} task',
)
    
# Check that secondary_pass1 is upstream to compare_pass1
self.assertTrue(
    all(
        task in all_upstream_task_for_compare_pass1_task
        for task in {secondary_pass1_task}
    ),
    f'one of {secondary_pass1_task} not found in upstream to {compare_pass1_task} task',
)
```

What I am refering to is the error message that is thrown when a unit test fails, although they are not exactly the same, the message is similar.

Is there a convention of creating a function and calling the function when throwing the error messages?

Comment: So, is your question purely about the `f'One of...'`  part?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I meant rather than repeating the error message over and over again, should I use a function to produce the error message, and each time I want to produce an error message to call on this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [non-f-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to define a string template that is then filled with variables:

```
compare_pass1 = "foo"
secondary_pass1_task = "bar"

s = 'One of {} not found in downstream to {}'

print(s.format(compare_pass1, secondary_pass1_task))

compare_pass2 = "fee"
secondary_pass2_task = "bas"

print(s.format(compare_pass2, secondary_pass2_task))
```

Comment: Is this convention when raising many similar error messages? Or is there no real convention to doing so?

Comment: I wouldn't call this convention, but it's a good way of defining similiar strings.

Comment: thank you I will use the above

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your own assertions to encapsulate the assertion logic and error messages.

You can define them as methods in your test class:

```
class YourTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertIsDownStream(self, all_downstream_tasks, task, original_task):
        self.assertTrue(
            all(task in all_downstream_tasks for task in {task}),
            f"One of {task} not found in downstream to {original_task} task",
        )

    def assertIsUpStream(self, all_upstream_tasks, task, original_task):
        self.assertTrue(
            all(task in all_upstream_tasks for task in {task}),
            f"One of {task} not found in upstream to {original_task} task",
        )

    # Your test cases here ...
```

Or you can define them in a separate class and use it as a mixin:

```
class CustomAssertions:
    def assertIsDownStream(self, all_downstream_tasks, task, original_task):
        self.assertTrue(
            all(task in all_downstream_tasks for task in {task}),
            f"One of {task} not found in downstream to {original_task} task",
        )

    def assertIsUpStream(self, all_upstream_tasks, task, original_task):
        self.assertTrue(
            all(task in all_upstream_tasks for task in {task}),
            f"One of {task} not found in upstream to {original_task} task",
        )


class YourTestClass(unittest.TestCase, CustomAssertions):
    # Your test cases here ...
```

Note that you may be able to define better names for the parameters based on your specific context.

Within your tests you can then simply use these assertions like so:

```
# Test that compare_pass1 is downstream to secondary_pass1
self.assertIsDownStream(all_downstream_task_for_secondary_pass1_task, compare_pass1, secondary_pass1_task)
```